# Location-aware iOS app with background support design issue

Tags: ios, background, core-location, cllocationmanager, foreground

I have location services enabled for updating locations when app in background, and I also listen for location updates when app in foreground, displaying a map. What should be the best way to design this scenario in iOS? I've thought about some options:

1) Having an instance of a class with a `locationManager` member that is its delegate itself. Then, in the body of the `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method, something like:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   if (!background) {
      // Perform some processing and notify the view controller which displays the map
      // by means of Notification Center
   }
   else {
      appDelegate.bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:appDelegate.bgTask];
         appDelegate.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
      }];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         // Perform some data processing 

         // Close background task
         if (appDelegate.bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:appDelegate.bgTask];
            appDelegate.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
         }
      });
   }
}
```

(Note: I'm not sure if having location services enabled as background service, it is needed to perform the processing of locations as if it were a finite background task...). The instance of such class could be a member of `AppDelegate`, and start listening for locations when entering background or calling the instance from the viewModel displaying the map. So, `AppDelegate` would have a reference to the instance managing the `locationManager`, and the map viewController would have a reference to `AppDelegate`, or communicate also by means of Notification Center.

2) Having the `locationManager` member directly in `AppDelegate`, and being the delegate itself.

Would it be better to encapsulate de locations listening and management in a different class, or handle it directly in `AppDelegate`? Having into account that I have to be able to listen for locations and perform some tasks both in foreground and in background.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best strategy is to have a singleton instance of a class that is a `locationManager` delegate. This instance would be responsible to filter whatever comes back from `locationManager` and ultimately assigns the location to one of its properties, let's call it `myLoc`.

This solves your centralized logic issues where the location needs post-processing after being acquired.

Second, in order to get the correct `UIViewControllers` and other class instances to do what they need when the location is updated, I suggest you use Key-Value Observing (KVO) on `myLoc`. I assume you know how that works. The reason I suggest KVO is that you need to trigger changes in multiple areas of the code based on the location being changed, and KVO is made for that kind of pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working with NSNotificationCenter until now but not KVO... it looks like KVO does more or less the same, why should it be better?

Comment: Take a look at the following, it gives a good overview of delegates, notifications and KVO. It's missing the blocks pattern, but it's good nonetheless: http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/06/14/delegation-notification-and-observation/

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add more to @Rikkles answer by saying that you can create a `BaseViewController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController` and has an instance of your singleton locationManager class too.
This approach allows us to move all the redundant code like, checking reachability, showing activity indicator,getting user location, etc to only one place and will be available to all other classes implementing it.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Since I also need to get location updates when app enters background, wouldn't it be better to have the singleton instance in `AppDelegate`, and then accessing it from the corresponding `UIViewController` when needed? On the other hand, having a "BaseViewController" could be a good idea